# React + Next js: Cross json values in component

Tags: json, reactjs

first I'd like to thank you for your time trying to help. I am a designer and I suck at developing stuff, so I have no other option than to scream for help.

So this is the situation:
I was asked to add an image (country flag) that's gonna be dynamic, in an element that fetches info from a JSON file with, among others, **Resorts** (one of the elements being its country's long name, i.e. *Australia*) and **Countries** (by long name and shortcode, i.e. *Australia*, *au*).

I need to get the country shortcode printed in the img src, but the resort array is only containing its long name.

The code:

This is the way the JSON file presents the information:

```
  {
    "Countries":[
       {"name":"Australia",
        "code":"au",
        "continent_code":"oc",
        "slug":"australia"}],
    "Continents":[
       {"name":"Oceania",
        "code":"oc",
        "slug":"oceania"}],
    "Resorts":[{
        "id":"1",
        "resort_name":"Resort Name",
        "encoded_name":"resort-name",
        ...
        "country":"Australia",
        ...}]
  }
```

And this is my file bit:

```
const DesktopResort = ({resort}) => (
    <Link href="/resort/[resort]"  as={`/resort/${resort.encoded_name}`}>
        <a target='_blank' className='resort-item'>
            <div className="resort">
                <div className="top">
                    <div className="title">{resort.resort_name}</div>
                    <img className="logo" src="/assets/img/resort-logo-sample.png" />
                    <span className="info">{`${resort.ski_network} - ${resort.region}`}</span>
                    // Down below is the "dynamic" file call
                    <img className="flag-icon" src={`/assets/img/flags/${resort.country}.svg`} />
                </div>
                <div className="arrow"><img src="/assets/img/arrow-link.png" /></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </Link>
)
```

I know its badly done right now, for this australian resort my image src is */assets/img/flags/**Australia**.svg* and what I would need to print is of course */assets/img/flags/**au**.svg*

How would you do it?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write a little helper function to look up a country code based on the country name.

Note: you'll need to handle what should happen if the country is not found, or the code is not there. I'm just defaulting to an empty string here.

```
const countryCode = name => {
  const country = yourData.Countries.find(country => country.name === name);
  return country && country.code || '';
};
```

Then use this when you're passing the `src` to your `img`.

```
<img 
  className="flag-icon" 
  src={`/assets/img/flags/${countryCode(resort.country)}.svg`} 
/>
```

Comment: This logic seems fine, but how should I define ' yourData '?

Comment: You posted your JSON data without a name. I named it "yourData". Just change it to the name you already using for that.

Comment: Thanks, total noob here!